# std::pair expecting a 'type', but I am giving it a type

Tags: c++, templates, stl

This is my code:

```
typedef std::hash_multimap<Vertice<VerticeType, WeightType>*, Edge<VerticeType, WeightType>*> ght;
std::pair<ght::iterator, ght::iterator> getEdgesFromVertice(Vertice<VerticeType, WeightType>*);
```

When I try to compile it, it gives me an error saying:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair’
error:   expected a type, got ‘__gnu_cxx::hash_multimap::iterator’
```

But isn't, std::hash_multimap::iterator a type? All the examples I've seen online use the same kind of notation for the return type of `std::hash_multimap<T1, T2>::equal_range(key)`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Sidenote: The singular is vertex, the plural vertices or vertexes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This looks like it is in a template and `VerticeType` etc. are template parameters. In that case you are missing `typename`:

```
std::pair<typename ght::iterator, typename ght::iterator> ...
```

Dependent names are assumed to [not name types](http://womble.decadent.org.uk/c++/template-faq.html#disambiguation) unless `typename` is used.